# Simple Java program - profiling shows unexpected behavior

Tags: java, performance, memory, profile

Given an extremely simple java program, shown below, I start the program and profile with VisualVM.

```
public class test {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{
      Thread.sleep(10000000L);
   }

}
```

As can be seen by the below metrics, something behind the scenes just keeps on ticking. What could possibly be going on behind the scenes here? I also included a screenshot of the "Sampler" memory and it looks as if a bunch of primitive arrays just keep getting created, why is this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you tell us how are you running this ? Also what are the parameters that are set for the JVM that its running on ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are connected to the process with VisualVM. Obviously, it takes *some* work to present you with the fact that the JVM is doing some work :) In specific detail, data is being collected and sent over the JMX connection. Some garbage is created.

Comment: It's called the "[Observer effect](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect)".

Comment: Kinda what I figured, would this exponentially increase if running in a multi-threaded environment?

Comment: You are always running in a multithreaded environment as you can see if you inspect the thread monitoring section in VisualVM. But no, tbis overhead is constant.